# Add a value from an array to another array if it dosen't exisist and filter it from the array if it does

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have:

```
const currentState = ['Godwin', 'Hadrada', 'Timujin', 'LaGrandBatard']
const selection = ['Atila', 'Godwin']
```

What's the best way to **remove the value from the first array if it already contains one of the values from the selection array** and to **add the value to it if it dosen't already contain one of the values**?

Just to make it more clear the end result should be:

```
newArray = ['Hadrada', 'Timujin', 'LaGrandBatard', 'Atila']
```

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. Try to solve the issue yourself before asking for help.

Comment: Tip: [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp

Comment: Eh free coding serivce?! that's a hell of a program there, I can makie it to the moon and back with it!  I have tried filter and for loops and includes but nothing quite fits

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the value from the first array if it already contains it" (what is "it"). Can you be more specific and add the desired result for the 2 array you posted as your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to this problem. Here's one using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) + [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
const currentState = ['Godwin', 'Hadrada', 'Timujin', 'LaGrandBatard'];
const selection = ['Atila', 'Godwin'];

const newState = selection.reduce((a, s) => {
  var i = a.indexOf(s);
  if (i === -1) {
    a.push(s);
  } else {
    a.splice(i, 1);
  }
  
  return a;
}, [...currentState]);

console.log(...newState);
```

To modify the collection in place just use `currentState` instead of `[...currentState]`

Here's another, more concise solution with `reduce` and a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const currentState = ['Godwin', 'Hadrada', 'Timujin', 'LaGrandBatard'];
const selection = ['Atila', 'Godwin'];

const newState = Array.from(selection.reduce(
  (a, s) => (a.has(s) ? a.delete(s) : a.add(s), a),
  new Set(currentState)));

console.log(...newState);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const currentState = ['Godwin', 'Hadrada', 'Timujin', 'LaGrandBatard']
const selection = ['Atila', 'Godwin']

let foo = {}
currentState.forEach(bar => {
  foo[bar] = true
})
selection.forEach(bar => {
  if (foo[bar]) {
    delete foo[bar]
  } else {
    foo[bar] = true
  }
})
const results = Object.keys(foo)

console.log(results)
```